# Orthogonal Data in R Data Tables (DT::datatable)

Tags: r, datatables, shiny, dt

Is it possible to add orthogonal data for sorting by column in an R datatable (takes only 2D data.frames or matrices)?

I've made a datatable for my shiny app that takes PubMed data and displays it for the user.  I'm getting a list of HTML links for my citedBy column (they are numbers that link to a NCBI webpage).  However the sorting function doesn't sort via numeric type.  So I was attempting to add orthogonal data like so:

**server.R**

```
output$Manuscript <- renderDataTable(datatable({
    dat <- publication_fetch(author_list)
    citedBy <<- dat$citedBy
    pattern <- "</?\\w+((\\s+\\w+(\\s*=\\s*(?:\".*?\"|'.*?'|[^'\">\\s]+))?)+\\s*|\\s*)/?>"
    num <<- NULL
    for(item in citedBy){
        plain.text <- gsub(pattern, '', item)
        plain.num <- as.numeric(plain.text)
        num <- c(num, plain.num)
      }

    dat
    },
    filter = "top",
    escape = FALSE,
    rownames = NULL,
    style = 'bootstrap'),
    options = list(
      columnDefs = list(
        list(
          target = 6,
          display = citedBy,
          sort = num
        )
      )
    ))
```

I have a feeling I'm implementing it wrong, and that these datatable options may not even be possible with 2D data.frames and matrices in R.  I'm looking for a work-around or other possible solutions to this sorting issue.